# jQuery - click function firing too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I'm writing a function detect if `$("input[name='AAA']")` input has changed, and if input changed, click apply button it will popup alert, but my alert message popup three times, how to avoid it?

HTML part:

```
<ul class="form">
<li>
   <span class="clumn1">Name:</span>
   <span class="clumn2">
      <input class="text" type="text" name="AAA">
   </span>
</li>
<li>
   <span class="clumn1">Address:</span>
   <span class="clumn2">
      <input class="text" type="text" name="BBB">
   </span>
</li>
<li>
   <span class="clumn1">Date:</span>
   <span class="clumn2">
      <input class="text" type="text" name="CCC">
   </span>
</li>
</ul>

<a class="submitBtn" onclick="apply()" href="#">Apply</a>
```

jQuery part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='AAA']").each(function() {
        var stuff = $(this);
        stuff.data('oldValue', stuff.val());
        stuff.bind("input", function(event){
            if (stuff.data('oldValue') != stuff.val()) {
                $(".submitBtn").on("click", function () {
                    alert("Your changed name is:" + stuff.val())
                });
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Must you code (jQuery) be something like that or it can be changed a lot?

Comment: Why this `$("input[name='AAA']").each..`?

Answer (score 0):

You're binding `click` event for the button every time the `input[name='AAA']` value is changed.

You should register `click` once and inside event handler compare old and new input value:

```
var stuff = $("input[name='AAA']");
var stuff_val = stuff.val();
$(".submitBtn").on("click", function () {
    if(stuff_val !== stuff.val()){
        stuff_val = stuff.val();
        alert("Your changed name is:" + stuff_val)
    }
});
```

```js
var stuff = $("input[name='AAA']");
var stuff_val = stuff.val();
$(".submitBtn").on("click", function () {
  if(stuff_val !== stuff.val()){
    stuff_val = stuff.val();
    alert("Your changed name is: " + stuff.val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="form">
<li>
   <span class="clumn1">Name:</span>
   <span class="clumn2">
      <input class="text" type="text" name="AAA">
   </span>
</li>
<li>
   <span class="clumn1">Address:</span>
   <span class="clumn2">
      <input class="text" type="text" name="BBB">
   </span>
</li>
<li>
   <span class="clumn1">Date:</span>
   <span class="clumn2">
      <input class="text" type="text" name="CCC">
   </span>
</li>
</ul>

<a class="submitBtn" href="#">Apply</a>
```